# Dynamic Type Assertion Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to convert an interface dynamically back to it's original struct but I am having issues accessing attributes of the struct after the conversion.

Take this code for example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type struct1 struct {
    A string
    B string
}

type struct2 struct {
    A string
    C string
}

type struct3 struct {
    A string
    D string
}

func main() {
    s1 := struct1{}
    s1.A = "A"
    structTest(s1)

    s2 := struct2{}
    s2.A = "A"
    structTest(s2)

    s3 := struct3{}
    s3.A = "A"
    structTest(s3)
}

func structTest(val interface{}) {
    var typedVal interface{}

    switch v := val.(type) {
    case struct1:
        fmt.Println("val is struct1")
    case struct2:
        fmt.Println("val is struct2")
    case struct3:
        fmt.Println("val is struct3")
    default:
        log.Panic("not sure what val is.")
    }

    fmt.Println(typedVal.A)
}
```

I would like to be able to pass in one of 3 known struct types into my function. Then figure out which struct type was passed in to type assert it. Finally I want to be able to access like attributes.

Basically I want to have some basic inheritance in my structs, but so far it seems that it is not possible to do this in go. I saw some posts mentioning inheritance using an interface, but my structs have no methods so I'm not sure how I would use an interface.

Is something like this possible in go?

Comment: why don't you return the value from the function. You are doing it right way just return the value to get the struct and then use it as required.

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go (I'm not sure what "inheritance using an interface" could mean, since interfaces implement a form of polymorphism). If you're looking for inheritance, you're trying to solve a problem with the wrong tools.

Comment: @Himanshu This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I guess I could grab the values and return them in a map or something. It just seems wasteful when I'm grabbing the same stuff from each struct but I have to copy paste it for each switch option.

Comment: @jhall1990 This is not possible to check the underlying type of an interface without knowing what type it can contains and then using switch to check. So either you can use map with key as name and value as struct. That way you will know the struct on basis of key and pass it to the function.

Comment: If this is not your real use case, what is. It seems I misunderstood your question, could you elaborate so we are better able to help you?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to be able to pass in one of 3 known struct types into my function. Then figure out which struct type was passed in to type assert it. Finally I want to be able to access like attributes.

You can use type assertions to do exactly that. Basic idea is, in any case of the type switch just use type assertion to get a concrete instance of the corresponding type and then you can call whatever properties that you wish.

Take a look at the following example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type test1 struct {
    A, B string
}

type test2 struct {
    A, C string
}

func testType(val interface{}) {
    switch val.(type) {
    case test1:
        t := val.(test1)
        fmt.Println(t.B)
        break
    case test2:
        t := val.(test2)
        fmt.Println(t.C)
        break
    }
}

func main() {
    t1, t2 := test1{B: "hello"}, test2{C: "world"}
    testType(t1)
    testType(t2)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9EAHsoqzj41)

Answer (score 0):

Function structTest(val interface{}) in your code seems to be loosely typed. You pass it an untyped argument and expect it will satisfy some condition (will have field A), it looks strange in any typed language.

Using an interface this kind of polymorphism, in Go, to my mind, can be expressed something like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type A string
type HasA interface {
    PrintA()
}

func (a A) PrintA() { fmt.Println(a) }

type struct1 struct {
    A
    B string
}

type struct2 struct {
    A
    C string
}

type struct3 struct {
    A
    D string
}

func main() {
    s1 := struct1{}
    s1.A = "A"
    structTest(s1)

    s2 := struct2{}
    s2.A = "A"
    structTest(s2)

    s3 := struct3{}
    s3.A = "A"
    structTest(s3)
}

func structTest(val HasA) {

    switch val.(type) {
    case struct1:
        fmt.Println("val is struct1")
    case struct2:
        fmt.Println("val is struct2")
    case struct3:
        fmt.Println("val is struct3")
    default:
        log.Panic("not sure what val is.")
    }

    val.PrintA()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0v71E07FP1u)